# Django Front End Search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, user-interface, heroku

Currently using Django 2.1,Python 3.6, PostgreSQL 11, and hosting the DB on Heroku.

I would like to implement a user search on a device view that I have setup.

[Current Page Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zaL6.png)
This page will list people in our DB and will provide a link to details about them. What I would like is for a user to be able to search for a particular person and have the list populate accordingly.

Django documentation provides some steps to implement this but is not entirely clear about an action plan.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: For reference there will be hundreds of people in our DB and it is currently hosted on Heroku.

EDIT: Models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
def __str__ (self):
    return self.top_name

class WebPage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('WebPage',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

EDIT: 
`# Search Code

```
def search(request):

    keywords=''

    if request.method=='POST': # form was submitted

        keywords = request.POST.get("keywords", "")
        all_queries = None
        search_fields = ('name__name','date') # change accordingly
        for keyword in keywords.split(' '): 
            keyword_query = None
            for field in search_fields:
                each_query = Q(**{field + '__icontains': keyword})
                if not keyword_query:
                    keyword_query = each_query
                else:
                    keyword_query = keyword_query | each_query
                    if not all_queries:
                        all_queries = keyword_query
                    else:
                        all_queries = all_queries & keyword_query

        accesses = AccessRecord.objects.filter(all_queries).distinct()
        context = {'accesses':accesses}
        return render(request, 'proj_app/search.html', context)

    else: # no data submitted

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'proj_app/index.html', context)`
```

Comment: you just need to make an ajax call on your text input change to fire to your server and query the user table by the value they pass.  Than get the results and pass them back to your view.  You'll need to bind the results via JavaScript to your UI.

Comment: Any way you could point me in a direction to a walkthrough of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to implement your own search engine in your views

```
def search(request):

    keywords=''

    if request.method=='POST': # form was submitted

        keywords = request.POST.get("keywords", "") # <input type="text" name="keywords">
        all_queries = None
        search_fields = ('title','content','resume') # change accordingly
        for keyword in keywords.split(' '): # keywords are splitted into words (eg: john science library)
            keyword_query = None
            for field in search_fields:
                each_query = Q(**{field + '__icontains': keyword})
                if not keyword_query:
                    keyword_query = each_query
                else:
                    keyword_query = keyword_query | each_query
                    if not all_queries:
                        all_queries = keyword_query
                    else:
                        all_queries = all_queries & keyword_query

        articles = Article.objects.filter(all_queries).distinct()
        context = {'articles':articles}
        return render(request, 'search.html', context)

    else: # no data submitted

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You just have to change the following :

1 - The name attribute used in html

```
<input type="text" name="keywords">
keywords = request.POST.get("keywords", "")
```

2 - The name of the model class

3 - The search fields of that model

Then in your search.html template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Author </td>
    </tr>
    {% for article in articles %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{article.title}}</td>
        <td>{{article.author}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Super helpful! How would I be able to populate alter my list population with results from the query?

Comment: There is no alteration to urls.py?

Comment: No you will have to link it to a url

Comment: The url would be for search.html?

Comment: Yes. For example : /search/ will redirect to search.html

Comment: When I use the search bar my url shows: /search/?keywords=Example
Then only reloads the page with no results. Where might I be implementing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your forgot to change the action of the form (eg: <form method="POST" action="/search/">

Comment: Now I am getting errors saying "Q" is not defined. What package would I import Q from?

Comment: from django.db.models import Q

Comment: I have foreign keys in the model I am querying would that cause an issue? I am seeing the error: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Comment: Not sure. If you want to reference a foreign key you can use the double underscore. Example : 'article__category__title'

Comment: that would be in the search_fields section?

Comment: Yes you add it to the search_fields list with other fields

Comment: In your example : 'article__category__title' 
Is category another model and the title is the attribute in the article table?

Comment: category is another model but title is the attribute in category not article

Comment: I am getting errors now saying that my field: 'accessrecord__webpage__name' 
cannot be resolved. Could this be due to the relations in my models? Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code of models.py

Comment: This is what I am seeing now: 
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'webpage' into field. Choices are: date, id, name, name_id

Comment: 'webpage__name' should be 'name__name' I think it will work now

Comment: this code you provided me only iterates through two fields in my models? Could you explain how I would be able to add the capability to search through more than 2 fields?

Comment: @cKdarlin47 you just add the field to the search_fields variable. It is a list (eg : search_fields = ('field1','field2','field3','field4')

Comment: I have tried entering more than two. The issue I am running into is that the query only searches through 2 fields on my machine. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: I think it depends on the keywords. The search splits the keywords string into words and then the query does an "or" filter on the fields. Maybe the keywords have words that don't have any match in database